# Почему переменная типа int требует приведения типа при присваивании?

Tags: java, переменные, int, приведение-типов

уважаемые. Простой вопрос. Почему происходит так, что при присваивании переменной результата выражения, которое возвращает вещественное число, всё компилируется без приведения типа; просто отбрасывается дробная часть и всё. Однако, если мы попробуем присвоить переменной типа `int` вещественное число, то выдаст ошибку, вместо всё того же элементарного отбрасывания, и мы вынуждены писать `(int)`.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5 / 2; //2.5
        int y = 2.5; //Ошибка.
        int z = (int) 2.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в первой строчке x будет 2.5. x это int. Будет 2 ответ. Int это целочисленное значение, и поэтому его надо обозначать. Иногда и double и float и long тоже явно указывать надо

Comment: А я не сомневаюсь что не будет 2.5. Я ж написал про отбрасывание дробной части. Ниже объяснили, что к чему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 5 / 2; // ne 2.5, a 2
```

Справа происходит "целочисленное деление", так как оба операнда - целые.

Попробуйте:

```
int x = 5.0 / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

- В первом случае это работает, потому что при делении целого числа в `java` остаток при делении отбрасывается (получится `2`).
- Во втором же случае мы явно присваиваем целому числу вещественное из-за этого приходится использовать приведение типов (опять же в переменной `x` получится `2`).